# Silverstripe and GoogleSitemap

Tags: php, silverstripe, xml-sitemap

i've just installed the GoogleSitemap for silverstripe and i add all of my object from db to xml and its fine. Also i need to add some routes which are not in database. I used the static class from documentation:

1)

```
GoogleSitemap::register_routes(array(
    '/my-custom-controller/',
    '/Security/',
    '/Security/login/'
));
```

and this code create this link in sitemap.xml:

```
sitemap.xml/sitemap/GoogleSitemapRoute/1
```

there is any way to create another group of link for another custom url? 
for example:

```
sitemap.xml/sitemap/GoogleSitemapRoute/1
sitemap.xml/sitemap/GoogleSitemapRoute/test
sitemap.xml/sitemap/GoogleSitemapRoute/test2
```

2) Second question:

Can i set the modify date for url added by register_routes method?

Thank you in advance!

ahh i forgot...
im using this library:
https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps